# Dropbox public link video - downloading onto an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, camera-roll

I'm trying to get this 70mb video, which I have uploaded to a public Dropbox folder onto this lady's iPad. She doesn't have a computer and I don't want her to have to do too much work to get this video into the camera. How exactly do i do this? The extremely useful Safari doesn't allow saving videos to the camera roll.

I should also add she wants to save the video to the camera roll, not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the app called Documents (https://readdle.com/products/documents). You can save all kinds of documents on it and it's easy to use and organize files on.